# Can you legally sue yourself?

Tags: litigation

I am asking about exact legal rules and principles regarding whether this would or would not be possible. This is not motivated by any pretext that it would be useful.

Can you submit a lawsuit to a court against yourself? Let’s assume there could be a variety of reasons why, but they share the theme of having committed wrongdoing against oneself. For example, maybe you have been severely negligent against yourself, and not treated yourself well in terms of health and lifestyle, causing chronic health issues. Or maybe you failed to set up adequate safety precautions for your own self-run business, and got injured. Regardless of the reason, the general context would be a sense of chastising yourself (i.e., there is not some ulterior, unsaid motive.)

Secondly, if you could win a very large lawsuit against yourself, legally, are you obliged to pay yourself that money via some kind of transfer of funds, ie, a check or bank transfer? And hypothetically, if the sum were greater than the amount of funds in your possession, could you declare bankruptcy since you cannot pay yourself the court-ordered amount? (Again, specifically what in the legal system would make this impossible, if it is - what laws).

Comment: Who is “myself”? If I sue a company where I am the sole shareholder and ceo and so on, would you call that “suing myself”?

Comment: @gnasher729 No, because you and your company are 2 different persons.